# In D3js, how do I cumulative add on every nth bound data value?

Tags: d3.js, call, modulo

I have this code which outputs a straight line composed of a bunch of line segments:

```
var width = 400;
var height = 100;
var data = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
var lineSegments = data.length + 1;

d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr({
            width: width,
            height: height
        })
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
        .append("line")
            .attr({
                x1: function (d, i) { return i * (width / lineSegments); },
                x2: function (d, i) { return (i + 1) * (width / lineSegments); },
                y1: function (d, i) { return height / 2; },
                y2: function (d, i) { return height / 2; },
                stroke: "black",
                "stroke-width": 2
            });
```

I want every 3d segment to be offset in the y direction by, say 10px, and I need the offset to be cumlative, i.e. the 3d element should have offset 10px, the 6th element should be offset 20px, etc.

This should result in a line like this:

[image]

How should I modify the code to get it to work? Is there a special d3 way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use d3's [`selection.each()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#each) to target every 3d segment. This method has some useful variables for performing various functions.

```
line.each(function(d, i) {
  console.log(i); // prints the current index
  console.log(d); // prints the data at the current index
  console.log(this); // prints the current DOM element
}
```

In your specific case, the `i` variable is useful to you. You can use this inside of an `if` statement to change the attributes of every 3rd element. Your revised code might be...

```
var width = 400;
var height = 100;
var data = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
var lineSegments = data.length + 1;

var offset = 5;

d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr({
            width: width,
            height: height
        })
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
        .append("line")
            .attr({
                x1: function (d, i) { return i * (width / lineSegments); },
                x2: function (d, i) { return (i + 1) * (width / lineSegments); },
                y1: function (d, i) { return height / 2; },
                y2: function (d, i) { return height / 2; },
                stroke: "black",
                "stroke-width": 2
            })
            .each(function(d,i) {
                if (i !== 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
                   d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + offset + ')');
                   offset += 5;
                }
            })
```

[Here is a working codepen.](http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/JYjmLe)

Comment: Nice! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: You can also simply do `.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0,"  + Math.floor(i / 3) * 10 + ")"; })`.